# Bootstrap: vertical align and margin problems with media queries

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, vertical-alignment

I'm building my first Bootstrap site after a few years of minimal coding. Just getting familiar with media queries and I've searched a lot but can't find a solution to this problem...

I'm trying to create a two-column section where one side is a responsive image and the other side is a paragraph of text. I'm trying to make the text align vertically centered to the image for sizes larger than medium. But I want it to collapse to one column for small and xs sizes. But I need to have different margins for each layout. Here's the code for the section and one nested row...

```
<div id="bio">
<div class="container">
<div class="row display-table">

   <div class="text-left col-md-6 display-cell">
     <p>Text...</p>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 display-cell">
     <img class="img-responsive img-rounded"  src="images/forest-park.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""/>       
   </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

with this CSS...

```
@media screen (min-width: @screen-md-min) {

    .display-table {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }

    .display-cell {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        float: none;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

}
```

Without the media query, this works perfectly with vertically aligned text at larger sizes. With the media query, it all collapses fine, but that bottom margin disappears and the paragraph is no longer vertically aligned.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you actually using [LESS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less) or do you need to change `min-width: @screen-md-min` to `min width: 992px` ?

Comment: Yeah, I've been using the prebuilt Bootstrap code with LESS. But I did try using pixels and it did the same thing.

Comment: You should add a working example Snippet that displays the problem then because it isn't clear.  If I use your code as plain CSS it seems to work as one would expect. See [Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)